# Identify pod which is not in a Ready state

Tags: kubernetes

We have deployed a few pods in  cluster in various namespaces. I would like to inspect and identify all pod which is not in a Ready state.

```
 master $ k get pod/nginx1401 -n dev1401
 NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
 nginx1401   0/1     Running   0          10m
```

In above list, Pod are showing in Running status but having some issue. How can we find the list of those pods.  Below command not showing me the desired output:

```
 kubectl get po -A | grep Pending Looking for pods that have yet to schedule

 kubectl get po -A | grep -v Running Looking for pods in a state other than Running     

 kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Failed
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a long-standing feature request for this. The [latest entry](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49387#issuecomment-663903782) suggests

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces | gawk 'match($3, /([0-9])+\/([0-9])+/, a) {if (a[1] < a[2] && $4 != "Completed") print $0}'
```

for finding pods that are running but not complete.

There are a lot of other suggestions in the thread that might work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```sh
$ kubectl get po --all-namespaces -w
```

- you will get an update whenever any change(create/update/delete) happened in the pod for all namespace

Or you can watch all pod by using:

```sh
$ watch -n 1 kubectl get po --all-namespaces
```

- This will continuously watch all pod in any namespace in 1 seconds interval.